# Value of a field is getting overlapped with subreport data

Tags: jasper-reports, subreport

I am working on a jasper report in which I am adding a sub-report to my parent report. Below sub-report, I am adding a static field which contains '$' value.

When I execute my report, the  '$' value is getting overlapped with the content of sub-report. I tried with position-type ' 'FLOAT' for static field and sub-report also, but its not working.

Here I attached screenshots for reference:

[image: Image 1]

and

[image]

The parent report content is in summary band and content of sub-report is in detail band. I am keeping content of main report because it contains many variables and if I put those in detail band then they are getting printed many times with different values.
Please help me to resolve this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It got resolved. Actually I kept top of static field touching with base of sub-report. When I tried with keeping small space between these two elements, its working fine.